# Decode a tuple using Json.Decode.andThen

Tags: elm

Using Elm 0.19.1, I have the following two functions:

```
criteriaDecoder : List Field -> List Operator -> Int -> List (Cmd Msg) -> ( Decoder Criterion, List (Cmd Msg) )
criteriaDecoder fields operators currentDepth cmdsList =
    field "type" JD.string
        |> JD.andThen
            (\fieldType ->
                criterionDecoder fields operators currentDepth cmdsList fieldType
            )


criterionDecoder : List Field -> List Operator -> Int -> List (Cmd Msg) -> String -> ( Decoder Criterion, List (Cmd Msg) )
criterionDecoder fields operators currentDepth cmdsList criterionType =
    case criterionType of
        "condition" ->
            let
                ( decoder, cmds ) =
                    conditionDecoder fields operators cmdsList
            in
            ( JD.map Condition <| decoder, cmds )

        "conditionGroup" ->
            let
                ( decoder, cmds ) =
                    groupDecoder fields operators currentDepth cmdsList
            in
            ( JD.map CriterionGroup <| decoder, cmds )

        _ ->
            ( JD.fail <| "Could not decode criterion for type: " ++ criterionType, cmdsList)
```

Basically, it should get the value from field `type` from the JSON. This value must be used to determine the right decoder in `criterionDecoder`. Both functions *must* return a `(Decoder Criterion, List ( Cmd Msg ))` object.

The problem is as following: In the `criteriaDecoder`, I use the `JD.andThen` function to get the value of the field `type`. However, this will create a type mismatch. The `JD.andThen` function expects a `Decoder` object, while the `criterionDecoder` will return a tuple of a `Decoder Criterion` and a `List ( Cmd Msg )`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Decode the data first separately. Then, after that, write a function that takes that data and updates state, creates commands, ...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot return `(Decoder Criterion, List ( Cmd Msg ))` if the `Cmd` values depend on what's being decoded, because the `Decoder` has not run yet (i.e. it doesn't know which `Cmd` values to return until it's used to decode some value).

If the `Cmd` values that you're returning depend on the input to the decoder (which seems to be the case), those `Cmd` values will need to be an output of the decoder. So, instead of `(Decoder Criterion, List ( Cmd Msg ))`, your decoder will *also* need to produce the `Cmd` values, `Decoder (Criterion, List ( Cmd Msg ))`.

Comment: That makes sense. I have fixed my problem by creating a new type of the object I needed. When the `Model` has been decoded, a function will loop through all `Criterion`'s and create a `Cmd Msg` when it encounters this type of object. After the `Cmd` has been executed, it will start again searching for this type of object, execute the `Cmd` etc. until all `Criterion`'s have been initialized. This solution is basically what @simon-h suggested in the comments.